# Removing rows after a certain value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R,

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,6,6), b=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1))
```

I want to remove the rows which has values for the variable b equal to 0 which occurs after the value equals to 1 for the duplicated variable a values.

So the output I am looking for is,

```
df.out <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,2,5,5,5,6,6), b=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1))
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick?

```
ind = intersect(which(df$b==0), which(df$b==1)+1)
df.out = df[-ind,]
```

The which(df$b==1) returns the index of the df where b==1. add one to this and intersect with the indexes where b==0.

Comment: Yours seems to output 10 rows, and the result from the OP has 9 rows. They want to get rid of all the 0's after 1's for each group. See differences in group "5"

Comment: ahh after the value that b=1? The sequence in b is 1,0,0,0,1 so should only result in 1,0,0,1 and not 1,0,1. Replace a with b in my code?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
df[ ave(df$b, df$a, FUN=function(x) x>=cummax(x))==1, ]

#        a b
#     1  1 0
#     2  1 1
#     4  2 0
#     5  2 0
#     6  5 0
#     7  5 0
#     8  5 1
#     11 6 0
#     12 6 1
```

Here we use `ave` to look within each level of `a` and we test to see if we've seen a 1 yet with `cummax`.